# What's wrong with the insert at the end operation in this Linked List?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I have written this code for implementing Linked List in c++. It worked perfectly till i added the insert at end function to it. Please see what's wrong! Without the insertatend function, output is correct. After adding that function, the output is 1 10 which is actually the insert at start and end's outputs.

```
void List::insertatend(int num)
{
    Node *new_node=new Node(num);
    if(listptr==NULL)
        listptr=new_node;

    else
        for(Node *temp=listptr; temp->next!=NULL; temp=temp->next)
            temp->next=new_node;
}
```

Comment: It's not an infinite loop because it stops when `next == NULL`. However, if OP ran through this code with a debugger they would spot the obvious bug in `insertatend`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the lines:

```
for(Node *temp=listptr; temp->next!=NULL; temp=temp->next)
        temp->next=new_node;
```

It seems like you haven't walked through the logic of how the code works.

You will first need to iterate until `temp->next` is `NULL` and then use

```
        temp->next=new_node;
```

The code to implement that logic is:

```
    Node* temp = listptr;
    for ( ; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next )
    {
       // Do nothing in the loop.
    }
    temp->next = new_node;
```

Here's the updated function:

```
void List::insertatend(int num)
{
   Node* new_node = new Node(num);
   if( listptr == NULL)
   {
      listptr = new_node;
   }
   else
   {
      Node* temp = listptr;
      for ( ; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next )
      {
      }
      temp->next = new_node;
   }
}
```

Comment: Your code fails to terminate the list with `new_node->next = NULL;`

Comment: @stark, the constructor of `Node` takes care of that.

Comment: Thanks! I understood it completely! :)

Comment: @RSahu Class `List` should guarantee that it builds a correct list.  It should not depend on the constructor of class `Node`.

Comment: @stark, that's a matter of coding practice. I like it that the OP made sure that constructor of `Node` set `next` to `NULL`.

Comment: @RSahu  I like it too, but the List class should make a list.  The Node class should make a node.  If you don't encapsulate correct behavior in a class, you are not writing correct code.

Comment: @stark, I don't see anything wrong with `List` depending on `Node` to set `next` to `NULL`. If one class/function cannot depend on another class/function for a certain behavior, we will be writing a lot of duplicate and redundant code.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the basic logic of how to add the every new node at end of previous  node.Bug is in below two lines of `insertatend` function, explanation I mentioned in comments.

```
 for(Node *temp=listptr; temp->next!=NULL; temp=temp->next) //it should be dummy loop
            temp->next=new_node;//In all old nodes next part will replace by new_node which is wrong
```

Modiy `Insert_end()` function as

```
void List::insertatend(int num)
{
        Node *new_node=new Node(num);
        if(listptr==NULL) 
                listptr=new_node;


        else{
                Node *temp=listptr; 
                for( temp ; temp->next!=NULL ; temp=temp->next); /** rotate dummy loop until temp is not reaching to last node **/
                temp->next = new_node;// in last node next put the new node address
                new_node->next = 0; // and new node nnext put the zero 
        }       
}
```

Comment: `new_node->next = 0;` needs to happen for both if and else.

Comment: You didn't need to make that change.  Note the `Node` constructor: `Node(int n)
    {
        data=n;
        next=NULL;
    }`.

Comment: Got it @user4581301

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!
I understood it well! :)